# Why does Emacs's format-time-string return a non-midnight value when given a zero-length duration?

Tags: emacs, time, elisp

When trying to format durations, Emacs returns unexpected values for the hour. Here, I print a zero-length duration.

```
(format-time-string "%H:%M:%S" (seconds-to-time 0))
```

returns `19:00:00`. Why isn't it `00:00:00`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of time zones. From the `format-time-string` documentation:

> The third, optional, argument UNIVERSAL, if non-nil, means describe TIME
>   as Universal Time; nil means describe TIME in the local time zone.

Emacs is treating that 0 as 00:00:00 UTC, but defaulting to convert that into local time. To not convert into local time, pass a non-nil value as the UNIVERSAL argument:

```
(format-time-string "%H:%M:%S" (seconds-to-time 0) t)
```

returns `00:00:00`